# Long list of error when I launch android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling

Whenever I launch android studio it gives me this error list:

```
Start failed

Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdt/eclipse/login/common/LoggerFacade
    at com.google.gct.login.ui.GoogleLoginActionButton.<init>(GoogleLoginActionButton.java:40)
    at com.google.gct.login.ui.GoogleLoginAction.createCustomComponent(GoogleLoginAction.java:42)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.getCustomComponent(ActionToolbarImpl.java:330)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.fillToolBar(ActionToolbarImpl.java:310)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.updateActionsImpl(ActionToolbarImpl.java:894)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.access$000(ActionToolbarImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl$1.updateActionsImpl(ActionToolbarImpl.java:168)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ToolbarUpdater$MyUpdateRunnable.run(ToolbarUpdater.java:191)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.flushRequest(FocusManagerImpl.java:675)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.flushNow(FocusManagerImpl.java:656)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.flushIdleRequests(FocusManagerImpl.java:626)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.access$200(FocusManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl$11.run(FocusManagerImpl.java:522)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2350)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(FocusManagerImpl.java:500)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ToolbarUpdater.updateActions(ToolbarUpdater.java:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ToolbarUpdater.updateActions(ToolbarUpdater.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.setMiniMode(ActionToolbarImpl.java:1268)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.<init>(ActionToolbarImpl.java:184)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.<init>(ActionToolbarImpl.java:147)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.createActionToolbar(ActionManagerImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.createActionToolbar(ActionManagerImpl.java:466)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeRootPane.createToolbar(IdeRootPane.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeRootPane.updateToolbar(IdeRootPane.java:193)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeRootPane.<init>(IdeRootPane.java:99)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl.createRootPane(IdeFrameImpl.java:184)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl.<init>(IdeFrameImpl.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.WindowManagerImpl.showFrame(WindowManagerImpl.java:514)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:306)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:172)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.common.LoggerFacade PluginClassLoader[com.google.gct.login, 1.0]
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:68)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 46 more
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: have you tried to import any eclipse project in android studio.? what is the project that is being loaded on launch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by uninstalling and reinstalling android studio and the android software development kit, after that things worked perfectly just like they did before, and I got back my previous projects.